# How to set goal parameters to solve a multiobjective problem with scipy.optimize?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have spent several hours trying to get my head around the `scipy.optimize.minimize function.`

I have got this working:

```
def poly_fun(coeffs,a,x):
        predicted=10**np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(np.log10(a),coeffs)

        slope,intercept,r_value,p_value,std_err=scipy.stats.linregress(x,predicted)

        return slope #intercept,r_value,p_value,std_err  

res=minimize(poly_fun,x0=original_polynomial,args=(a,x),method='Nelder-Mead')
```

I also have a plotting function in my poly_fun to visulise what is going on.

Basically I want to improve the slope and intercept rather than the automatic of r2 of my polynomial. This poly is transforming something and then Is compare against a set of ‘known’ data to see how good the estimation is, loop and repeat to hopefully get an optimized polynomial.

Maybe I am missing constraints? I can’t work out how to use them.

In matlab, functions like `fgoalattain` can take goal and weighting values during the optimization.

I would like to get my slope:1, r2:1 and intercept:0, or as close as possible. 
However, I can't work out which options in the function to use, or if I am using the wrong method or something. I haven't seen anything regarding goal attainment this in the documentation.

The code as is tries to make y =0 basically and flattens the linear trend to the bottom, where instead, I would like a 1:1

I have tried xtol, jac=True and some others, returning the slope, intercept, r2 but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Isn't the function for minimize in the form `f(x, *args)` instead of `f(*args, x)`? I actually don't quite understand, what your code is supposed to achieve (input, restrictions, output). It might be  helpful to post a simple input dataset with the expected output, so people can test their code. See [ How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It is not the best way to do this, but to test and better understand the question, does it works as you want if the `poly_fun` function returns `(slope-1)**2 + intercept**2 + (r_value-1)**2`?

Comment: @Mr.T The variable being minimized over is `coeffs`, while `x` is a fixed parameter, so it belongs in `args`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`minimize` looks for a minimum of a given (scalar) objective function. It does not deal with multiobjective problems. It can be used for multiobjective problems only by passing in a single objective function like `(slope-1)**2 + (r_value-1)**2 + intercept**2`.

However, in such cases it is preferable to use the specialized minimizer [`least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares), passing in a function that returns the vector `[slope-1, r_value-1, intercept]`. If you also want to attach weights `[w1, w2, w3]`, return

```
[w1, w2, w3] * [slope-1, r_value-1, intercept]
```

instead. So, with weights `3, 4, 5` it would be

```
def poly_fun(coeffs, a, x):
    predicted = 10**np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(np.log10(a), coeffs)
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = scipy.stats.linregress(x, predicted) 
    return np.array([3, 4, 5]) * np.array([slope-1, r_value-1, intercept]) 

res = least_squares(poly_fun, x0=original_polynomial, args=(a, x))
```

There are other `loss` functions besides the plain sum-of-squares that one can use in `least_squares`: see the docs.

Comment: Great. Thanks very much for your help here. I knew I was along the right track, but just couldn't work out which function I wanted. Cheers!